# NSTableView Delegate methods won't get called

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm currently trying to parse the reddit headlines from a specific subreddit and display these in an NSTableView. The thing is, the `numberOfRows` function gets called and returns the correct integer but the `tableView` delegate function never gets called.

As far as I can see everything is wired up correctly in the code.

ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    Downloader.load(url: URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/r/" + "gaming" + ".json")!){
        (result) in
        let tvc = TableViewController(data: result)

        self.tableView.delegate = tvc
        self.tableView.dataSource = tvc
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

TableViewController:

```
class TableViewController: NSObject{

    var json: JSON!

    init(data: JSON) {
        super.init()
        self.json = data
    }
}
extension TableViewController : NSTableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return JSONFormatController.getTitlesFrom(json: json).count
    }
}
extension TableViewController : NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        var titles = JSONFormatController.getTitlesFrom(json: json)
        if let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "entry", owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = titles[row]
            return cell
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The `result` variable and `getTitlesFrom` method do work, I checked these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that your `TableViewController` object is getting deallocated because you are not keeping a reference to it. Try this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
var tvc : TableViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    Downloader.load(url: URL(string: "https://www.reddit.com/r/" + "gaming" + ".json")!){
        (result) in
        self.tvc = TableViewController(data: result)

        self.tableView.delegate   = self.tvc
        self.tableView.dataSource = self.tvc
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Explanation: `tvc` is a local variable of the download block which is getting deallocated after it has executed. Presumably your assumption is that storing the `tvc` in `delegate` and/or `dataSource` is keeping `tvc` alive. But they are not, they are weak references.

Comment: Perfect, that did it! Thank you